# Uninstalling Eclipse Neon, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall, eclipse

I don't think this question is a duplicate, as the other question-askers that have reported this issue installed Eclipse using the command-line rather than the Eclipse installer.

I've been having issues with my Eclipse Neon installation and so I want to try a reinstall. I'm not sure how to do this, though, as I used the installer to install Eclipse so something like:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

Doesn't seem to work. The installer doesn't seem to have an uninstall option either, so I'm not sure what to do (I'm a Ubuntu noobie if you haven't guessed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't have a traditional install or uninstall process. Only a folder of an application is created plus the workspace which you created. If you used the Eclipse Installer, you may also have a bundle pool folder named **.p2** under your user home directory. There can also be .eclipse in your user home. Other than that, there shouldn't be anything Eclipse-related. Uninstalling is just removing those folders.

Based on comments from [Eclipse Community Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1073664/)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse provides two installation methods:

- Oomph based installer
- Good old-fashioned complete tar-ball

I've had serious issues with the first method,
the second works much better.
I recommend to download from [this page](https://eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/),
choose a flavor that's appropriate for you.
If you're not sure,
go for the first one, "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers".

Comment: How can I get rid of the Eclipse version I installed using the Oomph based installer? Can I just delete the folder? Not sure what I need to do in Ubuntu to safely get rid of everything.

Comment: You can simply delete the folder where it was installed.